# X axis on Time-Based data

Tags: charts, date-time, microsoft-excel-2011, axis

I have a series of 24 hr. data, taken about once per hour. I wish to plot the values against time. On day 1 the 10:00 data was taken at 10:10, on day 2 the data was taken at 9:58. I do not want both the 10:10 and 9:58 values to appear on the X axis. I want just 10:00 on the axis, with the first day's data to be placed somewhat right of the 10:00 line, and the second day just barely left of the line.

Can this be accomplished using Excel 11.6 on a Mac?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about Excel 11.6 (I don't use Mac), but this is pretty easy in Excel 2010, so I think it will apply.

1. Choose your data and insert into an XY chart.
2. Select your X-axis and open the format dialog box.
3. Manually set the min/max/major/minor values.

   - Set min as midnight for day 1 (you'll need to figure Excel's number for that date, e.g. 1/1/2012 00:00:00 = 40909).
   - Set max as midnight at end of last day (you'll need to calculate as above), or you can leave it as auto and it'll update as your data does).
   - Set major as 1.0, for one day increments (or modify to your preference).
   - Set minor as 0.041667 for one hour increments (or modifiy to your preference).
4. Format everything else to your taste.

[image: time based x-axis]

FWIW, with time values, the X-axis will get scrunched pretty fast, so you may not get much discernible detail on exactly where the points fall unless you're very zoomed in.  In the sample I've attached, there's only one day shown and the difference between 09:58, 10:00 and 10:10 is difficult to see, so consider how multiple days will impact that.